# Images ignores max-width on parent nodes

Tags: html, css

If I set the max-width css style on the body tag and a image inside the body is wider than the max-width of the body, the images will not obey the max-width. I want the image to resize, not just hide the overflow.

Why?

And how do you fix this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRMzs/

Comment: The image is larger than the body, therefore the body will expand. What exactly would you like to happen? Are you expecting the image to be cut, or resized?

Comment: That it would resize, so that the body will have the size of the max-width.

Comment: The specification that the image should resize needs to be edited into this original question.  I didn't see it before my first posting.

Answer (score 1):

max-width is not inherited automatically.

If you want specific tags to inherit the style width, you have to specify it explicitly to do, like this:

```
body
{
    max-width: 200px;
}

img
{
    max-width: inherit;
}
```

EDIT: Here's the link to the spec http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/max-width

Comment: Yes, max-width and min-width does not include padding, borders, or margins. Here's a good write up on calculating the CSS box total width and height: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel

Answer (score 0):

Images do not scale according to the parent `max-width` size.  You need to scale the images themselves to fit inside the content, making them `inherit` the parent width, or setting the `max-width:200px;`

If you do not want to scale pictures, but do not want the parent element to stretch, just use `overflow:hidden` and the extra portion of the image will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, setting width (especially `max-width`) on the `body` tag is bad practice for reasons I won't go into here.

In this case, it's the choice of using the `body` tag to define width that is causing you headache.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRMzs/17/

The only way to get the effect you are looking for is with a `#container` div of some kind (the CSS just can't target the `body` tag).

For the sake of making the answer visible on stackoverflow...

**EDIT: The request was made that the image flow to 100% the size of the container.  Just add `width: 100%` to the image.  Give it a special class to avoid this effect on all `<img>`'s**

the HTML you need is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="http://www.prepolino.ch/sprache/trennen/bilder/test.gif">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
body
{
}
#container {
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}
img {
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't resize the image

Comment: Margin on the image will break it.

Comment: Then don't put a margin on it.  Use a wrapper.  I have to say, you keep making special requests that aren't in the original question.  My answer is the closest to addressing the REAL question - the one that you actually asked before adding new conditions.  Just mark this as correct and move on.